# My $_GET is showing me empty string as a value

Tags: javascript, php, get

When I debug my $_GET as a parameter shows value that I want to display as value and where the value is it is showing me just empty string.

[image]

So I want on that place to be "reservationData" and {"thename":"Maja_Bj","themovie":"1","theday":"Saturday"} to be shown as value. I already defined thename, themovie, theday. Im just having trouble with switching positions with name and value of $_GET

Here is my code:

```
var reservationData = {}
console.log(reservationData);
debugger;
confirmReservation.on('click', function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: '/drupal/movie-reservation',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(reservationData),
    success: function(data){
      if(data.status == 'success'){
        alert("Success! Your information has been saved!");
      }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        alert("Error! Please try again...");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Its not very clear, but are you asking how to look at the data in your $_GET array? If so then `echo $_GET['thename'];` and so on

Comment: Just `data: reservationData`

Comment: Its also a bit odd as you never seem to load an data into `var reservationData = {}` before attempting to send it to the PHP code

Comment: someone posted the answer but it is not visible. that answer was correct - { reservationData: JSON.stringify(reservationData) }

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for taking time to answer my question. But, that was not the answer I was looking for. I wanted "reservationData" to be the name as parameter of my $_GET, but as you can see in my question it was showing me the value of it, not the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
data: {'reservationData':JSON.stringify(reservationData)}
```